How to set custom headers for CORS use?
I'm trying to add a custom header Attachment-Name to the response returned by an HTTP get triggered azure function (written in typescript, using v4 programming model, running with Azure Functions Core Tools Version: 4.0.5907 and Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875. I have
 "Host": { "CORS": "*" }
set in my local.settings.json file. However, when I call the azure function from the browser, I only get the CORS white listed headers in the browser. I tried setting Access-Control-Allow-Headers manually in my azure function, but that had no effect.
https://github.com/gosqasorg/asset-provenance-tracking/blob/coco-harry-attachment/packages/backend/src/functions/httpTrigger.ts#L175

async function getProvenance(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    const deviceKey = decodeKey(request.params.deviceKey);
    const deviceID = await calculateDeviceID(deviceKey);
    context.log(`getProvenance`, { accountName, deviceKey: request.params.deviceKey, deviceID });

    const containerExists = await containerClient.exists();
    if (!containerExists) { return { jsonBody: [] }; }

    const records = new Array<ProvenanceRecord & { deviceID: string, timestamp: number }>();
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ prefix: `gosqas/${deviceID}/prov/` })) {
        const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
        const { data, timestamp } = await decryptBlob(blobClient, deviceKey);
        const json = new TextDecoder().decode(data);
        const provRecord = JSON.parse(json) as ProvenanceRecord;
        records.push({ ...provRecord, deviceID, timestamp });
    }
    records.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
  return { jsonBody: records };
}


How do I configure Azure Function Core Tools to allow a custom header to be accessed in a CORS browser request?
